# Cannot access closed stream error when trying to send data from my WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

On my service I am trying to create and return a `MemoryStream` like this:

```
// Write data.
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (StreamWriter txtwriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string tempString = "Test";     
    txtwriter.Write(tempString);
    txtwriter.WriteLine();    


    // End response.
    memoryStream.Position = 0L;
    response.ReportMemoryStream = memoryStream;
    response.Length = memoryStream.Length;
    return response;
}
```

Note: having the `End response` part outside the `using` statement causes a `Cannot access a closed stream error`.

My `response` is a simple `DataContract`. When I try to read this data in my client doing something like this:

```
// Write stream.
if (remoteReport.ReportMemoryStream != null)
{
    remoteReport.ReportMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

I get again the same error about the stream being closed.

How can I fix this issue and why is my stream closing even though I'm not explicitly doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

`response.ReportMemoryStream = memoryStream;`

with

`memoryStream.CopyTo(response.ReportMemoryStream);`

now you are using reference type I think, and your `using` statment is just disposing stream you are using.

Comment: Hi, I followed your advice, but at the same time Amit's `Flush()` comment was useful too. Thus I am marking this as a correct answer, since there is no need to remove the `using block` and I'm up-voting Amit's answer.

Comment: @dearn44 if you use flush with using block you should check if the application wont crash with bigger streams

Comment: I see, depending on how big you mean, I dont thin I will have issues. I will do some tests nonetheless.

Comment: flush is "pushing" stream out, becouse this C# beeing is not exacly counted as normal object and some rules do not work with streams. It can work if the "push" method is fast enough to not push already closed stream by finally block (using statment is calling .dispose in hidden finally block)

Comment: I would actually be very interested in learning how to transfer very big files, of 1M rows as an example, using a `MemorySream`. I should open a new questions for this.

Comment: OK just did. The question may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865363/best-way-of-creating-and-transferring-larger-text-files-using-a-stream)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to flush your `StreamWriter` instance, so it writes to the `MemoryStream` instance -

```
 txtwriter.Flush();
```

Then you'll need to remove the `using` block, so the `txtwriter` doesn't by default destroyes the `memoryStream`.

Comment: Hi, seems there is no need to remove the `using` block, but `flush`ing was needed indeed.